# How to get the JAAS LoginContext or Subject on my JSF Managed Beans

Tags: jsf-2, authorization, jaas

I'm developing a security solution JAAS based, I developed the custom LoginModule and the authorization proccess was successful. But I need to get the javax.security.auth.Subject on my JSF Managed Beans to get the user Credentials.

I've tried:

`javax.security.auth.Subject.getSubject(java.security.AccessController.getContext());`

but it returns null.

Can anyone help me to get the Subject or the LoginContext current instance?

Comment: Isn't `ExternalContext#getUserPrincipal()`, `#getRemoteUser()` and `#isUserInRole()` sufficient?

Comment: @BalusC, nope, because I have a complex dataType that represents my user from LDAP and I need to get informations about the current user on my Managed Bean. So, I put these informations on Subject.getPublicCredentials().